# How to show and hide the header in section of tableView by navigation bar button tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Developing an iOS application with Xcode ver 9.3, Swift.

Could you tell me how to show and hide(switch) the header in section of tableView by navigation bar button tapped?

- Search bar is put in header in section to make it always visible while scrolling tableview
- I would like to hide the search bar in the initial display
- and, show and hide the search bar by tapping navigation bar button

The code and the screenshot are as follows.

**Code**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let array = ["apple", "orange", "melon", "banana", "peach"]
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Search", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(searchTapped))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchButton
    }

    @objc func searchTapped() {
        // If searchBar is hidden, then show a searchBar.

        // If searchBar is shown, then hide a searchBar.

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search..."
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        return searchBar
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        return searchBar.frame.height
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var hideSearchBar = false     // Class global var

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
     return hideSearchBar ? 0.1 : searchBarHeight
}  

@IBAction func search(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     hideSearchBar = !hideSearchBar
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Remember to keep height of section header as **0.1** if you want to hide searchBar. Keeping height **0** won't work.

Comment: The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @TakeYourMark : Anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` [Appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614855-tableview) from `UITableViewDelegate` method. As follows

```
override viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     yourBarButtonTapped = false

     //rest of your code
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
     return yourBarButtonTapped ? 0.1 : current_height
}

@IBAction func barButtonTapped() {
     yourBarButtonTapped = true
     yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@objc func searchTapped() {
    // If searchBar is hidden, then show a searchBar.
    tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
    // If searchBar is shown, then hide a searchBar.
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
    tableView.reloadData();
}
```

Or you could define:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

// if you don't need header then return nil or return uiview for header...

}
```